# Secure Eureka Client Service Endpoints

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

I want to communicate between several microservices. Better said: I only want to trigger a function in different microservices. Therefore I have to call some functions in that.
So I found eureka. My question is: Is there a way to only let eureka communcate to the microservice(s)?
Because I know the microservices need rest endpoints and I dont want any other people or mashcines to communicate to them except eureka.
Can anyone help?
Another question ist: I want to have the eureka server insde a docker container and all my other microservices, which register to it are also in a docker container. The microservices are registering, but on status, the URL (actuator) shows http://:: instead of the right url to get the status info. when I click on it. of course this is not working. How to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

1. put micro-serives and eureka behind a firewall so that outsides can not access them without permission.
2. Do you expose your microservices in dockerFile to be accessed? if not, please use EXPOSE command in dockerFile to a port and make it to be accessed.

Comment: of course I exposed the port of the microservices